# Update information in database using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I'm quite new to programming, and im trying to update a certain column in a database using php and javascript.

The data base only has 2 columns, seatnums and status. Basically, i want the status to reset back to 1 if the status is currently 0. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

I have a class inside a div in my HTML:

```
<a class='two' href="javascript:databaseReset() ">Reset</a>
```

My javascript function (Part im struggling with):

```
    function databaseReset();
    $.ajax({
        url: "dbreset.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'seatnum': seatnum,
            'status': '1'
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("ok");
        }

function over(id) {
    selectedseat=$(id).attr('title');
    $(id).attr('src','images/mine.gif');
    $(id).attr('title', 'Available');
}

function out(id) {
    $(id).attr('src','images/available.gif');
}
```

my php file:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

$query="UPDATE seats SET status=1 WHERE status=0";

$link = mysql_query($query);
if (!$link) {
 die('error 2');
}


?>
```

Comment: You should read up on how to use the $_POST variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it was simply a typo, but your function call needs to wrap brackets around the ajax call:

```
function databaseReset(){   //<---*****Add these braces*****
  $.ajax({
    url: "dbreset.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'seatnum': seatnum,
      'status': '1'
    },
    success: function () {
        alert("ok");
  }
};  //<---*****Add these braces*******
```

your code seems to declare the function, but not assign its functionality

Also, the data section is unnecessary, as it is not used. In fact, since you are not posting data, you can use the "GET" method instead.

Beyond that your code looks good, can you please specify what the issue is?

Comment: it wont run my onmouseover events when i put it in, think thats the main issue, and i cant discover why its causing the whole javascript file to stop working. Also, even when i click the reset button, nothing happens currently, so there may be an issue with connecting it all up

Comment: In order to debug your connection, I would recommend running your php page directing by calling from the URL, and instead of calling die, use a conditional print statement that echo's 'success' or 'failure' based on the result of the query

Comment: For the onmouseover event, I am not sure when and on what you are calling it. If you could provide additional code that highlights this issue, I would love to take a look and see if I can help. But as mentioned above, I would first run an isolated php page to ensure your connection works properly and your credentials are allowing you access to db. Also, it helps to open your browser's console, and make sure it is set to persist so you catch all errors your js may be throwing. This can give you specific line numbers, which help for debugging.

Comment: The database connection is fine, just ran it there in the URL, displaying no errors. The onmouseover is a separate function in the javascript file, so it shouldn't affect it. Then once i comment out the reset function, it works again.

Comment: What is the target of your onmouseover? Can you possibly include that function so I can see it? Also, when reset function is not commented out, are there any errors thrown to your console?

Comment: Please view my initial answer... Is that exactly how it is written in your code? Because if so, the $.ajax function must be wrapped within the databaseReset function. On the line function databaseReset(); you must remove the semicolon, add an opening brace {  and then below your $.ajax function add a closing brace }

Unless it was just a typo when entering it into stackoverflow lol

Comment: Ahh! Sussed it! Silly mistake. Tiredness has got the better of me! Thanks